# How to improve algorithm with respect of time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm trying to measure time complexity of my algorithm:

```
public boolean rotateAndCompare(int[] fst, int[] snd) {
    int len = fst.length;
    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (fst[(k + j) % len] != snd[j]) {
                break;
            }
            if (j == len - 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My assumption that it has `O(n*n)` complexity because we iterate through an array and then through another one array. Am I right? And If so then how can I improve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about code-improvement belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are right in which the complexity for the nested loops itself is O(n^2), and that is only approximate if either of those conditions within the nested loop are met in the first conditional check. However, to really solve your question, you would need to look at the scope of your program and how it is structured. You can't just ask how to improve it without knowing what to do. If you really require nested loops, then your going to get a complexity that increases exponentially...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, your algorithm decides if the first `fst.length` integers of `snd` are equal to `fst`, possibly rotated. It assumes that `snd.length >= fst.length`. If that isn't what you meant, please specify in the question.

But assuming that's what you really meant, you can solve this problem in O(n) using a string matching algorithm like [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). You need, in other words, see if you can find `snd` as a subarray of `fst + fst`, and that's a classic problem.

Here's an example implementation in Java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static class KMP {
        private final int F[];
        private final int[] needle;

        public KMP(int[] needle) {
            this.needle = needle;
            this.F = new int[needle.length + 1];

            F[0] = 0;
            F[1] = 0;
            int i = 1, j = 0;
            while (i < needle.length) {
                if (needle[i] == needle[j])
                    F[++i] = ++j;
                else if (j == 0)
                    F[++i] = 0;
                else
                    j = F[j];
            }
        }

        public int find(int[] haystack) {
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            int n = haystack.length, m = needle.length;

            while (i - j <= n - m) {
                while (j < m) {
                    if (needle[j] == haystack[i]) {
                        i++;
                        j++;
                    } else break;
                }
                if (j == m) return i;
                else if (j == 0) i++;
                j = F[j];
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static boolean rotateAndCompare(int[] fst, int[] snd) {
        int[] fst2 = new int[fst.length * 2];
        System.arraycopy(fst, 0, fst2, 0, fst.length);
        System.arraycopy(fst, 0, fst2, fst.length, fst.length);

        int[] snd2 = Arrays.copyOf(snd, fst.length);
        return new KMP(snd2).find(fst2) >= 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(rotateAndCompare(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{3, 1, 2, 4}));
        System.out.println(rotateAndCompare(new int[]{1, 2, 2}, new int[]{3, 1, 2, 4}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you tried with: `fst = {0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1}` and `snd = {0, 0, ... 0, 0, 1, 0}` ?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Yes, `System.out.println(rotateAndCompare(new int[]{0, 0, 0, 1}, new int[]{0, 0, 1, 0}));` => `true`

Comment: I'm Sorry, I made a mistake, your answer is really a great answer!

Answer (score -6):

O(n*n) is usually expressed as "order n-squared", O(n^2), which your algorithm is. However, since you do absolutely no length checking it could break altogether, which is more serious than algorithmic complexity. 'snd' (what does that stand for? Why so terse?) might not even have 'len' elements. Also, you can get a little improvement by making your terminal condition part of the loop control instead of checking it twice.

The risk of a crash is far more serious than algorithmic complexity. Once you solve that, you might be able to refactor the indexes to make it more linear, but I suspect that's not possible. If there are symmetries in your problem you might be able to exploit them.